# XPath Expression for parent element

Tags: xml, xpath

looked in some articles about this topic, but they all kind of differ to what I am trying to get.

My example XML file:

```
<AdditionalInformations>
    <AdditionalInformation>
        <Codes>
            <Code type="own">AAA</Code>
            <Code type="foreign">ZZZ</Code>         
        </Codes>
        <Value>MyValue</Value>
    </AdditionalInformation>
    <AdditionalInformation>
        <Codes>
            <Code type="foreign">BBB</Code>
        </Codes>
        <Value>2173.123</Value>
    </AdditionalInformation>
    <AdditionalInformation>
        <Codes>
            <Code type="own">CCC</Code>
        </Codes>
        <Value>true</Value>
    </AdditionalInformation>
</AdditionalInformations>
```

Now I what the xPath to get "MyValue". The requirements are the following:

- Code type must be "own"
- Code value must be AAA

I tried this expression:

```
/AdditionalInformations/AdditionalInformation/[Codes/Code[@type="own"]="AAA"]
```

but I am not sure how to get to the value-element from there.

Thanks for your help
Hauke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath :

```
'//Codes/Code[@type="own" and text() = "AAA"]/../../Value/text()'
```

#### Note

```
..
```

means *parent node*

Comment: For real? So easy? Thanks a lot!

Comment: XML is all about tree, I take advantage of this here to get parent like a directories in a unix shell ;)